# Reformat arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to take the elements from the 3 arrays located in the for loop (there are 11 elements per array)

```
for(var i= (UIyears - 5); i< UIyears + 6; i++) {
  var anneesListelenght = anneesListe.push(i+ " ans");
  var mensualiteTotaleListelenght = mensualiteTotaleListe.push(monthlyPayment + monthlyPaymentAssurance);
  var coutProjetListelenght = coutProjetListe.push(UIamount + totalPaymentAssurance + totalInterest);
}
```

and format them as follows:

```
var data =  [
  { Durée: anneesListe.value1, "Mensualité": mensualiteTotaleListe.value1,  "Coût total du crédit": coutProjetListe.value1},
  { Durée: anneesListe.value2, "Mensualité": mensualiteTotaleListe.value2,  "Coût total du crédit": coutProjetListe.value2},
  { Durée: anneesListe.value3, "Mensualité": mensualiteTotaleListe.value3,  "Coût total du crédit": coutProjetListe.value3},
];
```

Thank you very much for you reply but I have an error : "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

I am really a newbie...

This is the entire code :

```
// Listen for submit
document.getElementById("simulateur-form").addEventListener("submit", computeResults);

function computeResults(e) {

    // Récupération des données
    const UIamount = parseInt(document.getElementById("montant-total-projet").value);  
    const UIapport = parseInt(document.getElementById("apport").value);
    const UIinterest = parseFloat(document.getElementById("taux-pret").value);
    const UIinterestassurance = parseFloat(document.getElementById("taux-assurance").value);
    const UIyears = parseInt(document.getElementById("annee").value);


    //Compute monthly Payment
    const x = Math.pow(1 + (parseFloat(UIinterest) / 100 / 12), (parseFloat(UIyears) * 12));
    const monthly = (parseFloat(UIamount-UIapport) * x * (parseFloat(UIinterest) / 100 / 12)) / (x - 1);
    const monthlyPayment = monthly.toFixed(2);

    // Assurance
    const monthlyPaymentAssurance = ((parseFloat(UIinterestassurance) / 100 / 12)*(UIamount - UIapport)).toFixed(2);
    const totalPaymentAssurance = (monthlyPaymentAssurance * (parseFloat(UIyears) * 12)) ;

    // Mensualité totale
    const mensualitetotale = parseFloat(monthlyPaymentAssurance) + parseFloat(monthlyPayment);

    //Intérêts
    const totalInterest = (monthly * (parseFloat(UIyears) * 12) - parseFloat(UIamount-UIapport)).toFixed(2);

    // Cashflow
    const cashflow = (10858 - mensualitetotale);

    // Coût total
    const coutTotal = (parseFloat(UIamount) + parseFloat(totalInterest) + parseFloat(totalPaymentAssurance)).toFixed(2);

    //Formattage des résultats et affichage
    const UIamount1 = (new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(coutTotal)); 
    document.getElementById("UIamount1").innerHTML =  UIamount1;    
    const monthlyPayment1 = (new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(monthlyPayment));
    document.getElementById("monthlyPayment1").innerHTML = monthlyPayment1;
    const totalPaymentAssurance1 = (new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(totalPaymentAssurance));
    document.getElementById("totalPaymentAssurance1").innerHTML = totalPaymentAssurance1;
    const mensualitetotale1 = (new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(mensualitetotale));
    document.getElementById("mensualitetotale1").innerHTML = mensualitetotale1;
    const cashflow1 = (new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(cashflow));
    document.getElementById("cashflow1").innerHTML = cashflow1;
    const monthlyPaymentAssurance1 = (new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(monthlyPaymentAssurance));
    document.getElementById("monthlyPaymentAssurance1").innerHTML = monthlyPaymentAssurance1;
    const totalInterest1 = (new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(totalInterest));
    document.getElementById("totalInterest1").innerHTML = totalInterest1;


    var anneesListe = new Array(11);
    var mensualitepretListe = new Array(11);
    var mensualiteAssuranceListe = new Array(11);
    var coutTotalAssuranceListe = new Array(11);
    var coutTotalInteretListe = new Array(11);
    var mensualiteTotaleListe = new Array(11);  
    var coutProjetListe = new Array(11); 
    var cashflowListe = new Array(11); 


  var NBmois = (UIyears * 12);
for(var i= (UIyears - 5); i< UIyears + 6; i++)
    {
var anneesListelenght = anneesListe.push(i+ " ans");
var mensualitepretListelenght = mensualitepretListe.push(((UIamount - UIapport) * x * (parseFloat(UIinterest) / 100 / 12)) / (x-1));
var mensualiteAssuranceListelenght = mensualiteAssuranceListe.push((parseFloat(UIinterestassurance) / 100 / 12) * (UIamount - UIapport));
var coutTotalAssuranceListelenght = coutTotalAssuranceListe.push(monthlyPaymentAssurance * NBmois);
var coutTotalInteretListelenght = coutTotalInteretListe.push(monthlyPayment * NBmois - (UIamount - UIapport));
var mensualiteTotaleListelenght = mensualiteTotaleListe.push(monthlyPayment + monthlyPaymentAssurance);
var coutProjetListelenght = coutProjetListe.push(UIamount + totalPaymentAssurance + totalInterest);
var cashflowListelenght = cashflowListe.push(10858 - mensualitetotale);
}







// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("graphsimu", am4charts.XYChart);

chart.numberFormatter.intlLocales = "fr_FR";

// Data for both series
var data =  [
  { Durée: "10 ans", "Mensualité": 5400,  "Coût total du crédit": 49000},
  { Durée: "11 ans", "Mensualité": 5000, "Coût total du crédit": 54000 },
  { Durée: "12 ans", "Mensualité": 4600, "Coût total du crédit": 60000 },
  { Durée: "13 ans", "Mensualité": 4300, "Coût total du crédit": 70000 },
  { Durée: "14 ans", "Mensualité": 4000, "Coût total du crédit": 75000 },
  { Durée: "15 ans", "Mensualité": 3800, "Coût total du crédit": 84000 },
  { Durée: "16 ans", "Mensualité": 3650, "Coût total du crédit": 90000 },
  { Durée: "17 ans", "Mensualité": 3600, "Coût total du crédit": 98000 },
  { Durée: "18 ans", "Mensualité": 3400, "Coût total du crédit": 108000 },
  { Durée: "19 ans", "Mensualité": 3200, "Coût total du crédit": 115000 },
  { Durée: "20 ans", "Mensualité": 3000, "Coût total du crédit": 124000 },
];

/* Create axes */
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "Durée";
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;


/* Create value axis */
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
var valueAxis2 = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis2.renderer.opposite = true;
valueAxis2.syncWithAxis = valueAxis;


var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.categoryX = "Durée";
series.dataFields.valueY = "Mensualité";

series.columns.template.tooltipY = 0;
series.columns.template.strokeOpacity = 0;


var lineSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
lineSeries.dataFields.valueY = "Coût total du crédit";
lineSeries.dataFields.categoryX = "Durée"; 
lineSeries.stroke = am4core.color("#880000");
lineSeries.strokeWidth = 3;
lineSeries.yAxis = valueAxis2;



var bullet = lineSeries.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());

var circle = bullet.createChild(am4core.Circle);
circle.radius = 4;
circle.fill = am4core.color("#880000");
circle.strokeWidth = 3; 
chart.data = data;


/* Add a single HTML-based tooltip to first series */
series.tooltipText = `[bold] {Durée}[/]
----
Mensualité : [bold]{Mensualité} €[/]
Coût total du crédit : [bold]{Coût total du crédit} €[/]`;
series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";





// as by default columns of the same series are of the same color, we add adapter which takes colors from chart.colors color set
series.columns.template.adapter.add("fill", function(fill, target) {
  return chart.colors.getIndex(target.dataItem.index);
});

/* Create a cursor */
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();





  e.preventDefault();
}
```

How do I proceed ?
Thank you.

Comment: ok can you please also post the current format of the 3 arrays as well.

Comment: This really needs more explanation.  Can  you update with the current format (as Anees asked for) and some explanation of `value1`, `value2`, etc.  Are these actual properties of objects or just your pseudocode version of array indices?

Comment: With the additional details, I voted to reopen.  But it could still use some explanatory text.  It's not clear what part of your code is working and what isn't, and what precisely you're looking to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the for loop to push to an array of objects instead, so you don't have to transform them again later:

```
const arr = [];
for(var i= (UIyears - 5); i< UIyears + 6; i++) {
    const entry = {
        'Durée': i+ ' ans',
        'Mensualité': monthlyPayment + monthlyPaymentAssurance, 
        'Coût total du crédit': UIamount + totalPaymentAssurance + totalInterest,
    };

    arr.push(entry);
}
```

Comment: While this does answer the question, I have a query. Can we do `.push` directly without crating a `const` ?

Comment: @LearningEveryday yes you can but that makes it hard on eyes.